# foldl vs foldr: which should I prefer?

Tags: sml, smlnj

I remember that when I showed some code that I wrote to my professor he remarked, offhand, that

> It rarely matters, but it's worth noting that `fold*` is a little bit more efficient than `fold*'` in SML/NJ, so you should prefer it over `fold*` when possible.

I forget whether `fold*` was `foldr` or `foldl`. I know that this is one of those micro-optimization things that probably doesn't make a big difference in practice, but I'd like to be in the habit of using the more efficient one when I have the choice.

Which is which? My guess is that this is SML/NJ specific and that MLton will be smart enough to optimize both down to the same machine code, but answers for other compilers are good to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prefer the one that converts the given input into the intended output.

If both produce the same output such as with a sum, and if dealing with a `list`, folding from the left will be more efficient because the fold can begin with head element, while folding from the right will first require walking the list to find the last element before calculating the first intermediate result.

With arrays and similar random access data structures, there's probably not going to be much difference.

A compiler optimization that always chose the better of left and right would require the compiler to determine that left and right were equivalent over all possible inputs. Since `foldl` and `foldr` take a functions as arguments, this is a bit of a tall order.

Answer (score 4):

`foldl` is tail-recursive, while `foldr` is not. Although you can do `foldr` in a tail-recursive way by reversing the list (which is tail recursive), and then doing `foldl`.

This is only going to matter if you are folding over huge lists.

Comment: The SML Basis Library documentation does not address implementation details, including tail-recursion in `foldl` and `foldr`, so there is no way of knowing if `foldr` is implemented in terms of `foldl` or not. Per the documentation, the only difference is between `f(xn(...f(x1, init))` and `f(x1(...f(xn, init))`. It is also worth noting that the SML Basis Library provides `foldli` and `foldri` for arrays and presumably, the only difference is the order in which array indices are iterated. This would not affect tail recursion. Other languages, such as Racket, do vary in space requirements.

Comment: Actually, `foldr` may be tail-recursive with some accumulating functions. Example. Finding an element satisfying a predicate `p`. Accumulate with `fn (e, acc) => if p e then SOME e else acc`.

Comment: @beroal: Nope. Whether `foldr` is tail-recursive is not dependent on its arguments. Whether it is tail-recursive depends on whether the recursive call is in a tail position, and it is not (the result of the recursive call is passed to the accumulating function, and arguments are evaluated first before the function can be called).

Comment: @newacct: Yes. But if the accumulating function is inlined…

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to keep the accepted answer here, but I had the chance to speak to my professor, and his reply was actually the opposite, because I forgot a part of my question. The code in question was building up a list, and he said:

> Prefer `foldr` over `foldl` when possible, because it saves you a `reverse` at the end in cases where you're building up a list by appending elements during the fold.

As in, for a trivial example:

```
- val ls = [1, 2, 3];
val ls = [1,2,3] : int list
- val acc = (fn (x, xs) => x::xs);
val acc = fn : 'a * 'a list -> 'a list
- foldl acc [] ls;
val it = [3,2,1] : int list
- foldr acc [] ls;
val it = [1,2,3] : int list
```

The `O(n)` save of a reverse is probably more important than the other differences between `foldl` and `foldr` mentioned in answers to this question.